# To have Google Calendar Location links point to other Map application?

Tags: google-calendar, 8.0-oreo, maps

Currently, the links point to Google Maps which I cannot use during offline modes, for instance. 
I would like to have Here Maps as my default Maps application generally, but primarily I need them for my Calendar links.

I found several threads 2015 for the change which methods do not work anymore in the current Android.

OS: Android 7.1.1 (not supported, verified), now Oreo 8.0

Phone: OnePlus 3T

Other Map application: Here We Go (Here maps, past)

Answer (score 1):

You can try an of the following to open the links in other gps applications (Here Wego in this case);

1. **Editing links opened by default with Google Maps**

   - To adjust this behaviour, go to Settings ➡ Apps ➡ Maps ➡ Open by default ➡Open supported links ➡ Here you can select the appropriate choice e.g (Ask every time)

In this way location links are not automatically opened by Maps app rather you can select the one you wish to use e.g Here WeGo

(*Note remember to clear the defaults first*)

2. **Using [Send to GPS app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bestapps.sendtogps&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dsend%20to%20gps&pcampaignid=APPU_1_M0cMWpjmLYTOgAaQs7S4CA)**

> With this application you can send your position, or any other POI,
>   using Google maps to your GPS program

This in turn allows once to open the links directly from the target application. *Although not listed some users have be reported its compatibility with Here WeGo.*